# Fluid mechanics in non-inertial coordinates

Tags: fluid-dynamics, differential-geometry, reference-frames, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

Standard formulation of fluid mechanics valid in inertial frames, i.e. Navier-Stokes equation:

$$\partial_t v^i +v^j\partial_j v^i -\nu \Delta v^i = f^i/\rho $$

allows to co to non-cartesian coordinates fairly easily using standard formulas of differential geometry for example. But if one wants to change to non-inertial frame the fact that vectors are 3-dimensional while change of coordinates involves 4 complicates the situation. Is there any more geometric formulation of that equation that would make use of 4-dimensional space-time structure?

I tried using some ideas of [that blog post](https://altexploit.wordpress.com/tag/galilean-spacetime/), constructing $h^{ij}$ and covariant derivative to reproduce inertial frame equation, defining viscous term as $\nu h^{ij}\nabla_i\nabla_j \xi^k$ and advection term as $\xi^i\nabla_i\xi^k$, but I'm not sure if that's the correct way to proceed since the equation I get for rotating reference frame are a little bit peculiar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is using a "covariant" formalism in classical mechanics. I do not know how accommodate your equations in particular, but a good notion of *covariant derivative* that  physically encompasses the "inertial forces" (as in GR) is at disposal also in classical physics.

Consider the classical spacetime $M$. There there is a privileged class of reference frames called **inertial** such that changing (Cartesian) coordinates among them
$$t=t'+c\:, \quad x^{i} = R^i\:_j x^{'j} + v^it' + b^i\:, \quad i,j= 1,2,3 \tag{1}$$
for $R\in O(3)$, $c, v^i, b^i\in \mathbb R$
Instead, general transformations of coordinates (always Cartesian) at rest of generic reference frames are all of the form (in view of the fact that lengths  are absolute at every given time)
$$t=t'+c\:, \quad x^{i} = R^i\:_j(t') x^{'j} + b^i(t')\:,  \quad i,j= 1,2,3 \tag{2}$$
for arbitrary (smooth) functions $\mathbb R \ni t \mapsto R(t) \in O(3)$ and 
$\mathbb R \ni t \mapsto b^i(t) \in O(3)$.

In inertial reference frames *inertial motions* are described by **geodesics** 
$$t= v^0s+ c^0\:, \quad x^i(s) = sv^i + c^i\:,\quad v^0 \neq 0\:.$$
Indeed, they these are solutions $\gamma : \mathbb R \to M$ of the **geodesic equation** 
$$\frac{d^2x^a}{ds^2} + \Gamma^{a}_{bc}\frac{dx^b}{ds}\frac{dx^c}{ds}=0\:, \quad a,b,c =0,1,2,3$$
where $$\Gamma^{a}_{bc}=0\:,\tag{3}$$
with the requirement that $v^0\neq 0$, i.e. $\langle dT, \dot{\gamma}\rangle \neq 0 $, where $T: M \to \mathbb R$ is the **absolute classical time**, defined *up to an additive constant* and always coinciding with the coordinate $t$ and $t'$ (up to an additive constant).

All that means that the spacetime of classical physics, *as soon as we switch on dynamics* according to Newtonian picture,    a *non-metric*, *symmetric* **affine connection** arises determining inertial motions.

This connection  is trivial *just in the Cartesian coordinates at rest with  every inertial reference frame*. Indeed, it is easy to see that the condition (3) is invariant under transformation of coordinates of the form (1).

Instead, passing to a **non-inertial** reference frame equipped with (Cartesian) coordinates $x^{'a}$ where $x^{'0}=t'$ by means of (2), we have
$$\Gamma^{'a}_{bc} \neq 0$$
and, referring to (2) where the coordinates $t,x^i$ are supposed at rest with an inertial reference frame, since
$$\Gamma^{'a}_{bc} =\frac{\partial x^{'a}}{\partial x^d} \frac{\partial^2 x^{d}}{\partial x^{'b}\partial x^{'c}} + 0\:, $$
we have
$$\Gamma^{'0}_{bc} =0\:,  \quad \Gamma^{'i}_{0j}= \Gamma^{'i}_{j0} = (R^{-1})^{i}_{m}\dot{R}^m_j(t)\:,\quad \Gamma^{'i}_{00}= (R^{-1})^{i}_{m}\ddot{R}(t)^{m}_jx^{'j} + (R^{-1})^{i}_{m}\ddot{b}^m(t)\:, \quad \Gamma^{'i}_{jk}=0\:.$$
In the non-inertial reference frame the geodesic equation (inertial motion) is the complete geodesic equation, where I have introduced the inertial  mass $m$ of the point of matter considered,
$$m\frac{d^2x^{'a}}{ds^2}= -m\Gamma^{'a}_{bc}\frac{dx^{'b}}{ds}\frac{dx^{'c}}{ds}\quad a,b,c =0,1,2,3$$
and the terms $-\left(\frac{dx^{'0}}{ds} \right)^{-2} m\Gamma^{'i}_{bc}\frac{dx^{'b}}{ds}\frac{dx^{'c}}{ds}$ are nothing but the various inertial forces written into a more abstract formalism.

Equipped with this affine connection (and taking advantage of the absolute spatial metric $\delta_{ij}$), **every** differential equation can be written in every coordinate system using the standard procedure, replacing every derivative $\partial_a$ with the corresponding *covariant derivative* 
$\nabla_a$. Inertial forces are automatically embodied in the formalism.

The technically difficult (but not impossible obviously) point is re-writing the coefficients $\Gamma$ in terms of $\vec{\omega}$ its derivative and the acceleration of the origin of the inertial reference frame with respect to the inertial reference frame. By comparing with the classical formula of inertial forces, if $\vec{\omega} = \omega^i {\bf e}'_i$ is the angular velocity of the non-inertial reference frame with respect to the inertial one, $\vec{x'} = x^{'i}{\bf e}'_i$ is the position vector in the non-inertial reference frame and $\vec{a}_{O'} = a^{'i}{\bf e}'_i$ is the acceleration of the origin of axes of the non-inertial reference frame with respect to the inertial one, and everything is represented in the axes ${\bf e}'_1, {\bf e}'_2, {\bf e}'_3$ of the non-inertial frame, it should be (using the Euclidean metric $\delta_{ij}$ to raise and lower indices)
$$\Gamma^{'i}_{0j} = \Gamma^{'i}_{j0} = \omega^k \epsilon^i\:_{jk}\quad \mbox{Coriolis' force}$$
and
$$\Gamma^{i}_{00} = a_{O'}^i + \epsilon^i\:_{jk}\dot{\omega}^j x'^{k} + \omega^i x^j\omega_j - x^i \omega^j \omega_j \quad \mbox{drag force}\:.$$
I am not completely sure on this result as is the first time I try to get it.

Comment: That's a very beautiful  and complete answer. Indeed I realised that my confusion is coming from mixing vector fields in fluid mechanics and vectors tangent to geodesics in point-particle picture. One remark: are you sure about your connection transformation law? I thought it's $0-\frac{\partial^2 x^{'i}}{\partial x^m \partial x^p}\frac{\partial x^m}{\partial x^{'m}}\frac{\partial x^p}{\partial x^{'p}}=\Gamma^{'i}_{'p'm}$
Edit: they are actually equivalent

Comment: Thanks for the remark, I have corrected the internal sign of the geodesic equation and now every sign should be correct (obviously I am not completely sure :))

Comment: That's a technical question, but I'd add my own thoughts on using the mentioned formalism in context of hydrodynamics (Navier-stokes) equations. Shall I write separate answer or a long comment?

Comment: I suggest you to write another question so that also other people may answer. Bye, Valter

Comment: My original question was about fluids, so I don't know how to formulate what you suggested without making duplicate...